# Display time from string timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the date from time stamp using JavaScript but not working please check my code and it's not working due to string time but if i passed in number then it's working but this time coming from API so i must need to do something here. can anyone please help me.

```
var timestamp = '1607110465663'
var date = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(date.getTime())
```

Comment: Pass `timestamp` as number instead of a string. `var timestamp = 1607110465663;`.

Comment: you are right but i got this from API response so how can i convert it to string

Comment: You can use `new Date(~~timestamp);` or `new Date(+timestamp);`. There are many possibilities. Regarding maintainability, I would go for [`new Date(Number(timestamp));`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse string into **int** then...:

```
var timestamp = '1607110465663'
var date = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));
```

and use ***date*** object

```
console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to number using methods such as `Number` or `parseInt` before creating `Date` object.

e.g.

```
var timestamp = '1607110465663'
var date = new Date(Number(timestamp));
console.log(date.getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '' from timestamp

```
var timestamp = 1607110465663
var date = new Date(timestamp);
console.log(date.getTime())
console.log(date)
```

See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u2rwxgp/)

Comment: but i received the date in string format so i must need to convert any how in number format